# How to print the HTML source code from createpage in intern js

Tags: javascript, testing, intern

everyone!

So I have this intern code:

```
'Home page navigation bar: first load': function() {
      return util.createPage(this, '/')
        .then(function(){console.log('masuk');});
    }
```

I want to debug like that, but instead of printing `masuk`, I want to print all of the HTML source code of the page I made. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `createPage` is returning a Command chain, you could do:

```
util.createPage(this, '/')
    .getPageSource()
    .then(function (source) {
        console.log(source);
    });
```

The [getPageSource](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#getPageSource) method requests the HTML from the currently focused browser window or frame.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is to put your HTML inside a var and print it, after that you will manage with console.log your HTML var.

Comment: I don't know the code to get the HTML. Can you please tell me, Stephane? Thanks!